# Projection from a polytope to an affine space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $P\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ be some polytope defined by an intersection of half spaces with corresponding hyperplanes $H_k$, and let $A\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$
be some affine space, with $A\cap P \neq \Phi$.
Let $Q_{out}$ be the set of extremal points of $P$ ($0$-dimensional facets) whose projection onto $A$ lie outside $P$.

Suppose one would like to lower-bound the Euclidean distance
$$
min_{x\in Q_{out}} dist(x,A).
$$
Borrowing from $3$-dimensional intuition, could one use, as a lower bound, the distance from $A$ of any $1$-dimensional facet (line segment), belonging to a hyperplane $H_k$, for which $H_k \cap P \cap A \neq \Phi$ (a facet of $P$) ?